# Extract mail attachment and move to a target folder

Tags: pentaho, etl, kettle, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

My customer wants to send an excel data file (.xlsx) via Outlook mail. And I wish to extract this attachment and put it in a folder on the 'network' for further processing. 
I wish to use Pentaho for this process.

Mail comes --> Attachment Extracted --> Copied to a Directory on 'Network'

Now, after using the Pentaho step **'Email Messages Input'** for extracting the mail. How to move the extracted .xlsx file to a Target folder with Pentaho?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Move file task which you can use. Just provide source and destination paths. It moves complete folder as well as file. You can mention file path as per your requirements.

This task is in Job.

Hope this helps.